# Will installing Jupyter Notebook mess up the Hydrogen package in Atom?

Tags: macbook-pro, python

I recently downloaded and installed Python 3 from python.org because I wanted to use Hydrogen with Atom (the editor). From what I can gather, Hydrogen (in Atom) runs on (powered by?) Jupyter kernel. Hydrogen allows me to check code inside Atom. That feature is great. However, once I saw how Jupyter Notebook works, I really want to try Jupyter Notebook on my MacBook Pro (High Sierra).

As you can tell, even though I can manage to get things installed, that's the extent of my technical know-how. So I am wondering if installing Jupyter Notebook will disrupt/mess up the existing Jupyter (kernel?) operation.

My apologies for my awkward phrasing--I simply don't know what kernels are or how they work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered homebrew or anaconda? Both of these can simplify the installation and maintainance of python (and many other programs in homebrew's case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I  use both on my iMac with no problem. Both work fine. I also have High Sierra.

Comment: Did you use any packages to install Python3 (if that is even relevant)? Thanks btw!

Comment: I have both python 2 and python3. i run either one in a virtual environment.

Comment: I nstalled both using Anaconda.  I used that to set up my virtual environments too.